# Calculating percentage from meta key values of multiple wordpress posts between 2 dates

Tags: wordpress

I have 100 posts all have a meta_key named "isactive" whose value will either be "1" or "0"

I need to calculate the percentage of number of active posts(from 'isactive' metakey value) between any 2 dates

```
$args0 = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013',
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2013,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
        'meta_key' => 'isactive',
        'meta_value' => 0
    )

);
$count0 = new WP_Query( $args0 );

    $args1 = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013',
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2013,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
        'meta_key' => 'isactive',
        'meta_value' => 1
    )

);
$count1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );

echo $percent = $count0/$count1;
```

Whether this type of query works ?

Else is there any better way to calculate percentage based on the meta key values between 2 dates?

Comment: Why not just try to see if it works ?? And if not - then come back and say what is not working ..

Comment: And Percentage is usually calculated as `$percentage = $num_result/$num_Total*100;` - but that depends on how you want to format the result E.g. `round($num_result/$num_Total*100);`

Comment: I want to make sure whether the query pulls appropriate data. I'm just analyzing wordpress fits in all part of my projects requirements before i start to spend time on it.